# run function in a interval while also running main code

Tags: c++

Basically I am trying to run 2 pieces of code concurrently without freezing eachother, and one of the requires some delay.
so, initial code looks like this:

```
int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(166)); // this freezes the whole program for 166 ms
    // do other things
}
```

i have figured a way with threads:

```
void ThreadFunction() {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(166));
}


int main() {
    std::thread t1(ThreadFunction);
    t1.detach();
    // do other things while also doing what the thread t1 does without waiting 166ms
}
```

This is not exactly my code, but i am trying to recreate code that works as an example.

Threads work fine, but i hear people saying `thread.detach()` is not good.

So what are the alternatives?

Comment: its not quite clear waht you want to do. In your first example there is only one thread that does one thing. What are the "2 pieces" you want to run concurrently?

Comment: one thread should periodically print `"Hello world"` and the other?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 okay i will update the example

Comment: An atrernative to `thread::detach` would be `thread::join`

Comment: "but i hear people saying thread.detach() is not good." dont take it as an offense, but this is [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). `detach` is perfectly fine if you want to detach a thread. If you don't want to detach a thread, then you don't detach it

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i have updated the example

Comment: Detaching a thread might be bad because you loose control over it. If that's ok for you (for example if you don't care when and if this thread exits) do it. If you need to synchronise the thread later, detaching is a suboptimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example seems to be what you want. If you do not want to detach the thread, then don't do it. However, then you must `join` it and you can only `join` a thread when it finishes its work at some point.

For this simple example I suggest the following (otherwise you need a condition variable or similar to signal the thread that it should stop):

```
void ThreadFunction() {
    for (int i=0; i <100; ++i) {
        cout << "Hello World!";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(166));
    }
}


int main() {
    std::thread t1(ThreadFunction);

    // do other things while also doing what the thread t1 does without waiting 166ms

    t1.join(); // blocks until ThreadFunction returns
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For C++20 you can also use [std::jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread)

The difference to std::thread is that it will auto join on destruction, thus the code reduces to:

```
int main() {
    std::jthread t1(ThreadFunction);

    // do other things while also doing what the thread t1 does without waiting 166ms

    // t1.join() will be called automatically when the current scope exits
}
```

Comment: its not there in visual studio yet.

edit: in project settings enabled Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)
and ISO C17 (2018) Standard (/std:c17)

now it works

Comment: @MargaritaWeiß: That's because you have Visual Studio 2019, so C++20 is indeed a preview. However, Microsoft is working diligently to implement C++20, and VS2019 gets periodic updates to get closer to full C++20 compliance. See e.g. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c20-features-in-visual-studio-2019-versions-16-7-and-16-8/